# Wait() method in javascriptan us

Tags: javascript, wait

How can i use the wait() method in java script in order to postpone my submit?

Answer (score 1):

you can use setTimeout() function to delay any activity.

```
setTimeout("Func1()", 3000);
```

will delay the Func1() call by 3000 milliseconds.

To delay a form submit, do like this

```
<form>
<input type=text name="username" />
<input type="submit" value="submit" onClick="setTimeout('submit()',1250);">
</form>
```